# emacs always calls ipython with matplotlib

Tags: init-file, ipython

I'm trying using `ipython` in emacs. I installed `python-mode` and config `ipython`:

```
(require 'python-mode)
; use IPython
(setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")
(setq-default py-which-bufname "IPython")
(setq py-force-py-shell-name-p t)
(setq py-python-command-args '("-colors" "Linux"))
; switch to the interpreter after executing code
(setq py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
(setq py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
; don't split windows
(setq py-split-windows-on-execute-p nil)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-c i") 'py-shell)))
```

I didn't call `ipython` with `matplotlib`, but when I tried `C-c i` in emacs, I got:

```
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Eventloop or matplotlib integration failed.
Is matplotlib installed?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
....
ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

It's the same error with running `ipython --matplotlib`. I didn't install `matplotlib` because I don't want to use it. So, I didn't set it in my config.

Why did `emacs` still call `ipython` with `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython process reads `py-ipython-command-args`, which check.

BTW `py-buffer-name` is used as an internal variable, do not set it.

Comment: What did you mean? You can try `ipython --matplotlib` and got the same error if you don't install matplotlib. I have set the arguments for calling ipython, but emacs still called it with `matplotlib`.

Comment: @cuonglm Okay, got a glue, will correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Did it documented anywhere?

Comment: @cuonglm Great. For docu see README.org:  * Selecting a Python shell